# words usage database?

Tags: statistics, linguistics

Is there any free database/place out there with commonality/usage ratios of English words? (British or U.S. English, doesn't matter)

I don't care about the exact numbers, only relative to eachother. Something like:

the | 0.2
car | 0.08
chroma | 0.005
overspread | 0.0000007

**Edit:**

I have found http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aFrequency_lists which I can scrape for data. However I would prefer an sql-format which is easier to work with.

Comment: The relativities will depend on the age, race, sex, dialect, nationality, ... of the person. Seems rather a futile exercise to either collect or try to use that information IMHO

Comment: @Ed Heal - I'm looking for the general usage frequencies over the entire population. The source doesn't matter exactly, and it needn't be overly accurate, only usable.

Comment: Hi @manixrock, it has been four years since you asked this question. Have you found your satisfied source?

Answer (score 4):

The term you want to google is "word frequency". One of the top hits is http://www.wordfrequency.info/

Comment: That link is just for the written word! Differs somewhat from usage.

Comment: The link is not free. They only provide demos with 1% of the words. You have to pay $195 for academic purposes.

Comment: There are other google hits there for you, did you try? The corpus they extracted the information from is Available, so you could attempt it yourself. Or just go with http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English which is also among the results.