# Java library for keywords extraction from input text

Tags: java, nlp, extract, keyword, stemming

I'm looking for a Java library to extract keywords from a block of text.

The process should be as follows:

stop word cleaning -> stemming -> searching for keywords based on English linguistics statistical information - meaning if a word appears more times in the text than in the English language in terms of probability than it's a keyword candidate.

Is there a library that performs this task?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/). I didn't use the last version but the [3.6.2 one](http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/java/3.6.2/), since this is the one I know the best. Besides the `/lucene-core-x.x.x.jar`, don't forget to add the `/contrib/analyzers/common/lucene-analyzers-x.x.x.jar` from the downloaded archive to your project: it contains the language-specific analyzers (especially the English one in your case).

Note that this will *only* find the frequencies of the input text words based on their respective stem. Comparing these frequencies with the English language statistics shall be done afterwards ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7248868/1225328) may help by the way).

---

## The data model

One keyword for one stem. Different words may have the same stem, hence the `terms` set. The keyword frequency is incremented every time a new term is found (even if it has been already found - a set automatically removes duplicates).

```java
public class Keyword implements Comparable<Keyword> {

  private final String stem;
  private final Set<String> terms = new HashSet<String>();
  private int frequency = 0;

  public Keyword(String stem) {
    this.stem = stem;
  }

  public void add(String term) {
    terms.add(term);
    frequency++;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Keyword o) {
    // descending order
    return Integer.valueOf(o.frequency).compareTo(frequency);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
      return true;
    } else if (!(obj instanceof Keyword)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return stem.equals(((Keyword) obj).stem);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Arrays.hashCode(new Object[] { stem });
  }

  public String getStem() {
    return stem;
  }

  public Set<String> getTerms() {
    return terms;
  }

  public int getFrequency() {
    return frequency;
  }

}
```

---

## Utilities

To stem a word:

```java
public static String stem(String term) throws IOException {

  TokenStream tokenStream = null;
  try {

    // tokenize
    tokenStream = new ClassicTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_36, new StringReader(term));
    // stem
    tokenStream = new PorterStemFilter(tokenStream);

    // add each token in a set, so that duplicates are removed
    Set<String> stems = new HashSet<String>();
    CharTermAttribute token = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
    tokenStream.reset();
    while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
      stems.add(token.toString());
    }

    // if no stem or 2+ stems have been found, return null
    if (stems.size() != 1) {
      return null;
    }
    String stem = stems.iterator().next();
    // if the stem has non-alphanumerical chars, return null
    if (!stem.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9-]+")) {
      return null;
    }

    return stem;

  } finally {
    if (tokenStream != null) {
      tokenStream.close();
    }
  }

}
```

To search into a collection (will be used by the list of potential keywords):

```java
public static <T> T find(Collection<T> collection, T example) {
  for (T element : collection) {
    if (element.equals(example)) {
      return element;
    }
  }
  collection.add(example);
  return example;
}
```

---

## Core

Here is the main input method:

```java
public static List<Keyword> guessFromString(String input) throws IOException {

  TokenStream tokenStream = null;
  try {

    // hack to keep dashed words (e.g. "non-specific" rather than "non" and "specific")
    input = input.replaceAll("-+", "-0");
    // replace any punctuation char but apostrophes and dashes by a space
    input = input.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}&&[^'-]]+", " ");
    // replace most common english contractions
    input = input.replaceAll("(?:'(?:[tdsm]|[vr]e|ll))+\\b", "");

    // tokenize input
    tokenStream = new ClassicTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_36, new StringReader(input));
    // to lowercase
    tokenStream = new LowerCaseFilter(Version.LUCENE_36, tokenStream);
    // remove dots from acronyms (and "'s" but already done manually above)
    tokenStream = new ClassicFilter(tokenStream);
    // convert any char to ASCII
    tokenStream = new ASCIIFoldingFilter(tokenStream);
    // remove english stop words
    tokenStream = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_36, tokenStream, EnglishAnalyzer.getDefaultStopSet());

    List<Keyword> keywords = new LinkedList<Keyword>();
    CharTermAttribute token = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
    tokenStream.reset();
    while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
      String term = token.toString();
      // stem each term
      String stem = stem(term);
      if (stem != null) {
        // create the keyword or get the existing one if any
        Keyword keyword = find(keywords, new Keyword(stem.replaceAll("-0", "-")));
        // add its corresponding initial token
        keyword.add(term.replaceAll("-0", "-"));
      }
    }

    // reverse sort by frequency
    Collections.sort(keywords);

    return keywords;

  } finally {
    if (tokenStream != null) {
      tokenStream.close();
    }
  }

}
```

---

## Example

Using the `guessFromString` method on the [Java wikipedia article introduction part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)), here are the first 10 most frequent keywords (i.e. stems) that were found:

```
java         x12    [java]
compil       x5     [compiled, compiler, compilers]
sun          x5     [sun]
develop      x4     [developed, developers]
languag      x3     [languages, language]
implement    x3     [implementation, implementations]
applic       x3     [application, applications]
run          x3     [run]
origin       x3     [originally, original]
gnu          x3     [gnu]
```

Iterate over the output list to know which were the *original found words* for each stem by getting the `terms` sets (displayed between brackets `[...]` in the above example).

---

## What's next

Compare the *stem frequency / frequencies sum* ratios with the English language statistics ones, and keep me in the loop if your managed it: I could be quite interested too `:)`

Comment: So as I understand, the code has to run on an apache server. What if my software is supposed to be local?

Comment: @Shay Why would it need an apache server? I just put `KeywordsGuesser.guessFromString("input")` in a `public static void main(String[] args)` method to made the example.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Lucene and I see that the code is heavily relies on it so I've assumed that this is the case.
Any Idea on where such english dictionary of stems can be found?

Comment: @Shay You can have a list [here](http://www.wordfrequency.info/) but you'll have to pay to get the whole one. I found [this one](http://ucrel.lancs.ac.uk/bncfreq/flists.html) too, which seems to be quite interesting, but I can't assure it has relevant enough data.

Comment: It seems that version 3.x.x is no longer available. I had to download and try 4.4.0.
I don't know what's the problem but I get a null pointer exception when I try to execute the code.

Comment: @Shay Did you follow the link I gave ([link](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/lucene/java/3.6.2))? It seems to be still available.

Comment: @sp00m, thanks for the full code example, everything is working except one thing — stop words filtering. Could you, please, have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36241051/462347

Comment: unable to resolve ClassicTokenizer class using Lucene 6.1.0 , any help please ?

Comment: @sp00m I got this exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: TokenStream contract violation: reset()/close() call missing, reset() called multiple times, or subclass does not call super.reset(). Please see Javadocs of TokenStream class for more information about the correct consuming workflow.".

Comment: @sp00m I got it to work. You need 2 calls to reset() in guessFromString() and stem() methods

Answer (score 7):

An updated and ready-to-use version of the code proposed above.
This code is compatible with `Apache Lucene` 5.x…6.x.

***CardKeyword*** class:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Keyword card with stem form, terms dictionary and frequency rank
 */
class CardKeyword implements Comparable<CardKeyword> {

    /**
     * Stem form of the keyword
     */
    private final String stem;

    /**
     * Terms dictionary
     */
    private final Set<String> terms = new HashSet<>();

    /**
     * Frequency rank
     */
    private int frequency;

    /**
     * Build keyword card with stem form
     *
     * @param stem
     */
    public CardKeyword(String stem) {
        this.stem = stem;
    }

    /**
     * Add term to the dictionary and update its frequency rank
     *
     * @param term
     */
    public void add(String term) {
        this.terms.add(term);
        this.frequency++;
    }

    /**
     * Compare two keywords by frequency rank
     *
     * @param keyword
     * @return int, which contains comparison results
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(CardKeyword keyword) {
        return Integer.valueOf(keyword.frequency).compareTo(this.frequency);
    }

    /**
     * Get stem's hashcode
     *
     * @return int, which contains stem's hashcode
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.getStem().hashCode();
    }

    /**
     * Check if two stems are equal
     *
     * @param o
     * @return boolean, true if two stems are equal
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (this == o) return true;

        if (!(o instanceof CardKeyword)) return false;

        CardKeyword that = (CardKeyword) o;

        return this.getStem().equals(that.getStem());
    }

    /**
     * Get stem form of keyword
     *
     * @return String, which contains getStemForm form
     */
    public String getStem() {
        return this.stem;
    }

    /**
     * Get terms dictionary of the stem
     *
     * @return Set<String>, which contains set of terms of the getStemForm
     */
    public Set<String> getTerms() {
        return this.terms;
    }

    /**
     * Get stem frequency rank
     *
     * @return int, which contains getStemForm frequency
     */
    public int getFrequency() {
        return this.frequency;
    }
}
```

***KeywordsExtractor*** class:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.LowerCaseFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.StopFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.EnglishAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.PorterStemFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.miscellaneous.ASCIIFoldingFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.ClassicFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Keywords extractor functionality handler
 */
class KeywordsExtractor {

    /**
     * Get list of keywords with stem form, frequency rank, and terms dictionary
     *
     * @param fullText
     * @return List<CardKeyword>, which contains keywords cards
     * @throws IOException
     */
    static List<CardKeyword> getKeywordsList(String fullText) throws IOException {

        TokenStream tokenStream = null;

        try {
            // treat the dashed words, don't let separate them during the processing
            fullText = fullText.replaceAll("-+", "-0");

            // replace any punctuation char but apostrophes and dashes with a space
            fullText = fullText.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}&&[^'-]]+", " ");

            // replace most common English contractions
            fullText = fullText.replaceAll("(?:'(?:[tdsm]|[vr]e|ll))+\\b", "");

            StandardTokenizer stdToken = new StandardTokenizer();
            stdToken.setReader(new StringReader(fullText));

            tokenStream = new StopFilter(new ASCIIFoldingFilter(new ClassicFilter(new LowerCaseFilter(stdToken))), EnglishAnalyzer.getDefaultStopSet());
            tokenStream.reset();

            List<CardKeyword> cardKeywords = new LinkedList<>();

            CharTermAttribute token = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

            while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {

                String term = token.toString();
                String stem = getStemForm(term);

                if (stem != null) {
                    CardKeyword cardKeyword = find(cardKeywords, new CardKeyword(stem.replaceAll("-0", "-")));
                    // treat the dashed words back, let look them pretty
                    cardKeyword.add(term.replaceAll("-0", "-"));
                }
            }

            // reverse sort by frequency
            Collections.sort(cardKeywords);

            return cardKeywords;
        } finally {
            if (tokenStream != null) {
                try {
                    tokenStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get stem form of the term
     *
     * @param term
     * @return String, which contains the stemmed form of the term
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private static String getStemForm(String term) throws IOException {

        TokenStream tokenStream = null;

        try {
            StandardTokenizer stdToken = new StandardTokenizer();
            stdToken.setReader(new StringReader(term));

            tokenStream = new PorterStemFilter(stdToken);
            tokenStream.reset();

            // eliminate duplicate tokens by adding them to a set
            Set<String> stems = new HashSet<>();

            CharTermAttribute token = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

            while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
                stems.add(token.toString());
            }

            // if stem form was not found or more than 2 stems have been found, return null
            if (stems.size() != 1) {
                return null;
            }

            String stem = stems.iterator().next();

            // if the stem form has non-alphanumerical chars, return null
            if (!stem.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9-]+")) {
                return null;
            }

            return stem;
        } finally {
            if (tokenStream != null) {
                try {
                    tokenStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Find sample in collection
     *
     * @param collection
     * @param sample
     * @param <T>
     * @return <T> T, which contains the found object within collection if exists, otherwise the initially searched object
     */
    private static <T> T find(Collection<T> collection, T sample) {

        for (T element : collection) {
            if (element.equals(sample)) {
                return element;
            }
        }

        collection.add(sample);

        return sample;
    }
}
```

The call of function:

```
String text = "…";
List<CardKeyword> keywordsList = KeywordsExtractor.getKeywordsList(text);
```

Comment: I tried this code and it failed to run properly under Lucene 6.x.  I had to add some reset() calls on the token stream.  Also, it doesn't seem to handle dashed words properly...I noticed that a term like "industry-recognized" was replaced with "industry-0recognized" in an attempt to prevent the tokenizer from breaking up the word, but I still got a token "0recognized" so that hack didn't seem to work.

Comment: I was able to get passed the issue with the StandardTokenizer by using the WhitespaceTokenizer.  It seemed to handle dashed words just fine without the need of the hack.

Comment: I'm curious which jars and versions were used for this. I tried lucene-core for 4.9.0, 5.5.5, 6.5.5 and there were many compile errors in each case.

Comment: @MichaelEaster, this code has been _written_, _tested_ and _worked_ on Apache Lucene 6.4.1. Please, try to run this code on a plain Java-project with minimum dependencies and Apache Lucene 6.4.1. API could undergo some changes.

Comment: @MikeB. Thanks! It worked. I didn't realize that I needed another jar other than lucene-core. I will post a full, working solution here this weekend.

Comment: @MichaelEaster, «I needed another jar other than lucene-core», that's weird, as far as I remember, I used standard Lucune's jars.

Comment: @MikeB I have built this example using Gradle here - https://github.com/codetojoy/sandbox_lucene/tree/master/StackOverflow_17447045_original_post  ... Over the next few weeks, I might try to use the latest version of Lucene, and some other ideas (via other examples in the repo)

Answer (score 1):

A relatively simple approach based on the RAKE algorithm and [opennlp models](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/) wrapped by the [rapidrake-java](https://github.com/crew102/rapidrake-java) library.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import io.github.crew102.rapidrake.RakeAlgorithm;
import io.github.crew102.rapidrake.model.RakeParams;
import io.github.crew102.rapidrake.model.Result;

public class KeywordExtractor {

    private static String delims = "[-,.?():;\"!/]";
    private static String posUrl = "model-bin/en-pos-maxent.bin";
    private static String sentUrl = "model-bin/en-sent.bin";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream stopWordsStream = KeywordExtractor.class.getResourceAsStream("/stopword-list.txt");
        String[] stopWords = IOUtils.readLines(stopWordsStream, "UTF-8").toArray(new String[0]);
        String[] stopPOS = {"VBD"};
        RakeParams params = new RakeParams(stopWords, stopPOS, 0, true, delims);
        RakeAlgorithm rakeAlg = new RakeAlgorithm(params, posUrl, sentUrl);
        Result aRes = rakeAlg.rake("I'm looking for a Java library to extract keywords from a block of text.");
        System.out.println(aRes);
        // OUTPUT:
        // [looking (1), java library (4), extract keywords (4), block (1), text (1)]
    }
}
```

As you can see from the sample output you get a map of keywords with their relative weights.

<sup>As explained at https://github.com/crew102/rapidrake-java you need to download the files `en-pos-maxent.bin` and `en-sent.bin` from the [opennlp download page](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/), and put them into the `model-bin` folder in your project root (must be a sibling of your `src` folder if using the maven project structure). The stopwords file should go under `src/main/resources/stopword-list.txt` (assuming maven structure), can be downloaded for example from https://github.com/terrier-org/terrier-desktop/blob/master/share/stopword-list.txt.</sup>